# C# Why does OnItemDataBound fire before Page_Load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, asprepeater

I have a question about C# repeater. I have default width setting, and it will change base on some conditions in the Page_Load, I want change to be pass to my Image on OnItemDataBound. However, it seems that the OnItemDataBound is firing off before Page_Load because I changed the width to 700 in Page_Load, but when the image is loaded, it is always showing 380 instead. If OnItemDataBound is not the correct function to use, which function should I call so that I can change the image width after the Page_Load (where the custom width is set) is called? I tried OnPreLoad, OnLoad, and none of them worked.

```
 protected int width = 380;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        width = 700;
    }
}

protected void Test_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
    if ((item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        Image Image = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("Image");

        Image.ImageUrl = Utilities.generateImage();
        Image.Width = width;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Databinding is done on `PrerenderComplete` event, which is fired on page lifecycle before `PageLoad`. For more info check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events to see lifecycle events and their order.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the datasource in markup, it can render everything much earlier since you are not doing a manual databind. This can occur previous to Page_Load.

Try overloading an earlier event, such as OnLoad or OnPreLoad. Both of these occur prior to Page_Load.

If you are explicitly performing databinding and doing it in another event that occurs prior to Page_Load, then you'll have to ensure that the repeater is rebound if you want to change things. Once you call databind, it binds. If you need to change something either do it before or rebind.

Comment: I tried OnLoad and OnPreLoad and they are still not picking up my new width.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Page_Init for this. It fires before ItemDataBound:

```
  protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {         
     if (!Page.IsPostBack)
     {
        // load
     }
  }
```

See also:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178472(v=vs.100)